# addEventListener is running function on page load only javascript

Tags: javascript, function, input, addeventlistener

I've set up 2 event listeners on inputs. I'm trying to pass a variable on the first one so I can re-use the function on other areas of my code but it's not working. I re-created it without the variable and it works fine. Can someone please tell me what's going on?

```
<div id="t1">
   Not working -  <input class="font" id="font1"></input>
    </div>

<div id="t2">
   Working - <input class="font" value="pork" id="font2"></input>
    </div>

JS -     
var change = document.getElementById('font1');
var change2 = document.getElementById('font2');

function draw(variable) {
    console.log(variable);
    var font = document.getElementById(variable).getElementsByClassName("font")[0].value;
    console.log(change.value);
}

function draw2() {
    console.log(change2.value);
}

change.addEventListener("input", draw('t1'));
change2.addEventListener("input", draw2);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5mk18ou1/2/

Thanks

Comment: your first input has no value.. not getting your question..

Comment: It is supposed to pick up the value from the user input

Comment: add one more function, like  function draw3() {
    draw('t1');
}

change.addEventListener("input", draw3);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do like this:

```
change.addEventListener("input", draw('t1'));
```

You must give a function (they don't call it callback function for nothing) to the addEventListener, so something like this works

```
change.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
     draw('t1');
});
```

Comment: You should fix your formatting in that answer. But other than that, it's the right answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll need to read up on callback function (i'm pretty clueless) I will accept your answer in 8 minutes when the site allows me to :)

Comment: Maybe a small addition: if you ever need the `event` as well, put it in the callback: `change.addEventListener("input", function(event) {draw(event,'t1');});`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
change.addEventListener("input", draw('t1'));
```

to

```
change.addEventListener("input", function(){ draw('t1'); });
```

so you can call an anonymous function which can pass in the variable to `draw()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function reference to the `addEventListener`. What you are curerntly doing is pass the result of calling the `draw('t1')`.

You could either pass an anonymous function, or use `bind` to set the parameter beforehand

```
// anonymous function
change.addEventListener("input", function() { draw('t1'); });
```

or

```
// use bind
change.addEventListener("input", draw.bind(this,'t1'));
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/5mk18ou1/3/

Answer (score 0):

Why even passing the variable if you want the current value ?

Try this:

```js
var change = document.getElementById('font1');
var change2 = document.getElementById('font2');

function draw() {
    var font = this.value;
    alert(this.value)
}

change.addEventListener("input", draw);
change2.addEventListener("input", draw);
```

```html
<div id="t1">
   Not working -  <input class="font" id="font1"></input>
    </div>

<div id="t2">
   Working - <input class="font" value="pork" id="font2"></input>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because I didn't know about, it clearly this is something I need to investigate. It looks like a much more straightforward way of doing it. Thank you!